# Excel VBA HTML Nested QuerySelector

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

Consider this extract of an html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="BoxBody">
<span class="txt">20 Records found. </span>
<p style="text-align: right;"><span class="txt">[First/Previous] &nbsp;1&nbsp;, <a class="page" href="javascript:paginacao('paginar','2');" title="Go to page 2">2</a> [<a class="page" title="Next page" href="javascript:paginacao('paginar','next');">Next</a>/<a class="page" title="Last page" href="javascript:paginacao('paginar','last');">Last</a>]</span></p>
<br>
<span class="txt">25 Records found. </span>
<p style="text-align: right;"><span class="txt">[First/Previous] &nbsp;1&nbsp;, <a class="page" href="javascript:paginacao('paginar2','2');" title="Go to page 2">2</a> [<a class="page" title="Next page" href="javascript:paginacao('paginar2','next');">Next</a>/<a class="page" title="Last page" href="javascript:paginacao('paginar2','last');">Last</a>]</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the `anchor` tag that has the "next" page `href` (if it has one).

I tried this in the console using Firefox and it works:

```js
document.querySelector(".BoxBody > p:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)").querySelector("a[title='Next page']")
```

I put up a sample VBA code using `querySelector` as well, but it fails with `Invalid argument`.

```
Sub test()

Dim oFSO As Object, paginator As Object
Dim oFS As Object, sText As String

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\example.html")

Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
    sText = oFS.ReadAll()
Loop


Dim html As HTMLDocument, html2 As Object
Set html = New HTMLDocument
Set html2 = html
html2.Write sText

Set paginator = html.querySelector(".BoxBody > p:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)").querySelector("a[title='Next page']")

End Sub
```

What is causing this? The `p:nth-child(2)` identifier? 
How should I go to extract that element using VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nth-child(2)` is not supported in VBA and is indeed causing the error message. You can't use `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()`. There is very little implemented in libraries available to you that deal with pseudo-classes. You can use `first-child` interestingly. You will also find you are limited on which objects you can chain querySelector on.

```
Dim ele As Object, iText As String
Set ele = html.querySelector(".BoxBody > p > span:first-child > a[title='Next page']")
   
On Error Resume Next
iText = ele.href
On Error GoTo 0

If iText = vbNullString Then '<== This assumes that the href has a value otherwise use an On Error GoTo which will then handle the error and print "no href"
    Debug.Print "No href"
Else
   Debug.Print "href"
End If
```

---

EDIT: 29/5/21 As of some point in last month (?) it has become possible to use element.querySelector widely as well as the most of the standard pseudo-class selectors (at least for Windows 10, MSHTML.DLL 11.00.19041.985 (Date modified 12/5/21)

Comment: That was my first solution, but since there are two similar paginated tables in the page (with that same title attribute), I really need to check if that element exists inside that `.BoxBody > p:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)` element..

Comment: Ok. If there is enough to demonstrate the choice that must be made .

Comment: No, I want one match only (whether the 'next' button has an href, or not)

Comment: Please check the edited `html`. I only want to check whether the first `a` with title `Next page` has an `href` or not...And I cannot use `querySelectorAll` as it is constantly crashing Excel...

Comment: The first `a` tag with title `Next page`

Comment: Was thinking about something like `html.querySelector(".BoxBody").getElementsByTagName("p")(2).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).querySelector("a[title='Next page']")` but that doesn't seem to work also...

Comment: Please bear with me. Is the above closer to what you are asking? Just updated